# How Can I Set the Default Value of a DATE Column to the Current date with Laravel Migrations?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-migrations

I'm having some issues with creating a migration, one of the columns I have on the table is a DATE type, not DATETIME or TIMESTAMPS.
And the problem is that I can't find a way to define the default value for this column, I've tried the following:

```
$table->date('request_date')->default(Carbon::now());
//This uses the date the migration was created as a default, not the current date.

$table->date('request_date')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_DATE()'));

$table->date('request_date')->default(DB::raw('date(now())'));

$table->date('request_date')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_DATE'));
```

And using the DB:raw is giving me an error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Exception::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CURRENT_DATE() after `issue_date`, add `expiry_date` date null after `request_da' at line 1")

Any recommendation would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `$table->date('request_date')->default(date('Y-m-d'));` try this please

Comment: this should work `$table->date('request_date')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_DATE'));`

Comment: $table->date('created')->useCurrent();

Comment: Hey @SanuKhan unfortunately already tried that, and its giving me an error, seems like in MySQL there is no default to current date and that's the error because I've tried with all of the options from the answers to my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in MySQL, you can not set default to current date. In your case, you can use request_date as a TIMESTAMP fields, and in your model, you cast it to date format.

```
$table->timestamp('request_date')->useCurrent()
```

And in your model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'request_date' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
];
```

This way is much more flexible. If in the future, you need to get the time, you still can do it

Comment: This approach makes sense, and yes I've learned the hard way that in MySQL you cannot set the default to the current date, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` type only offers automatic initialization to the current date [From mysql doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html), so you can able to use Laravel Observer with `creating()` method to set current date.